# Furnace ignites sometimes but not other times

Tags: wiring, hvac, repair, heating, furnace

When my York gas furnace turns on, the ignitor heats up and glows red, then the gas valve turns on and I can hear gas flowing. About 50% of the time the burners ignite and the furnace runs great after that, but the other half of the time the gas turns on for a few seconds but the burners do not light. When the burners do not light, then fan still seems to be blowing but obviously does not pump any hot air. I tried replacing the ignitor and the flame sensor, replacing the air filter, but I am still having the same issue. If I turn the furnace off and then back on again, the burners will light sometimes but still not others. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be happening? Or any advice on what to try to fix my problem? This is an older York Stellar furnace.

Comment: Is the ignitor adjusted to light the gas property.  Might be out of adjustment and just catches the gas sometimes.

Comment: any changes in air flow around the furnace ? open/closed doors, other ?

Comment: Is the burner "gunked up" (holes plugged, etc.) or the igniter away from the holes in the burner so that gas doesn't have easy access to the igniter?

Comment: Is this a condensing furnace? The pressure switch can result in some strange behavior when it goes.